# Conditions of Green's theorem and Cauchy Goursat theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

(I am using [these lecture notes here](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/complex-analysis/complex_analysis.pdf).)

The proof of Cauchy's theorem uses Green's theorem. Concretely, Cauchy's theorem is the following theorem:

Let $D\subset \mathbb C$ be simply connected and $\gamma$ a closed curve in $D$ and $f:D\to \mathbb C$ holomorphic with continuous partial derivatives. Then $\int_\gamma f = 0$.

The proof is very short using Green's theorem. But Green's theorem does not require the domain of functions to be simply connected, [only connected.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)

---

But then one could do the exact same proof using Green to prove the following false theorem:

> Let $D\subset \mathbb C$ be **connected** and $\gamma$ a closed curve
>   in $D$ and $f$ holomorphic then $\int_\gamma f = 0$.

The problem is, this is false: Just consider the unit disk with $0$ removed and $\gamma$ its boundary.

> Please can someone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: "The proof of Cauchy's theorem uses Green's theorem." Some do, some don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying Green's theorem to $\gamma$ and the domain bounded by $\gamma$. If $D$ is not simply connected, the domain bounded by $\gamma$ may contain points **outside** $D$.

For a concrete example, let $D = \{ 0 < |z| < 2 \}$ and take $\gamma$ as the unit circle. Then $\gamma$ is the boundary of the unit disc, which contains $0$, and $0$ is **outside** of $D$.

Look at the pictures on page 49 in your notes for clarification.

Comment: Yes, exactly: and because there may be points outside $D$ but insisde $\gamma$ the Cauchy theorem would be false but we can still prove it using Green's theorem.

Comment: @learner No, you need Cauchy-Riemann to hold at every point **inside** $\gamma$ not just inside $D$.

Comment: On page 49 we can apply Green's theorem to picture (iii) in order to get that the integral in (iii) is zero.

Comment: Oh! Inside $\gamma$? I need a minute to reread everything.

Comment: No, I don't think that's true: consider the double integral over $D$ in [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem). Here $D$ is not simply connected. But $D$ is the area on which the CR equations must hold in order for the double integral to be zero. No?

Comment: Wikipedia says "$D$ is the region bounded by $C$" and I looked up the definition of region and it's just a connected set. Not necessarily simply connected.

Comment: Reread Green's theorem again. If $\gamma = \partial\Omega$ you can replace a curve integral along $\gamma$ by a double integral over $\Omega$. If $D$ is not simply connected, then $\Omega$ may contain points outside of $D$ (and ypu have no information abput $f$ at such points). The $D$ in your theorem is not the domain bounded by $\gamma$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are right: the domain is just everything inside $\gamma$ and therefore simply connected.